# Base 2 matrix logarithm in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, logarithm, exponential, natural-logarithm

I know there exists MATLAB functions for `log` and `log2`, and for matrix logarithm there is `logm`. But I was wondering how do I calculate matrix logarithm for base 2?

Answer (score 2):

it's just a change-of-base  to convert the base of the logarithm, you can just use `logm` as follows:

```
log2m=logm(M) ./ log(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

For a scalar `x`,

```
log2(x) = log(x)/log(2)
```

I see no reason why this wouldn't work with matrix logarithms: `logm(m)/log(2)`.

For example, let's take the matrix from [this example on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Constraints_in_the_2_%C3%97_2_case):

```matlab
issimilar = @(x,y) all( abs(x(:)-y(:)) < 1e-14 );

m = [1.25, 0.75; 0.75, 1.25];

issimilar( exp(1)^logm(m), m ) % returns true
issimilar( 2^(logm(m)/log(2)), m ) % also returns true
```